# How to refresh package.json file after git pull in a grunt task?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a grunt file which does the following tasks in order:

- Pefrorm a `git pull` command (grunt-shell)
- Uglify all the javascript files defined in *package.json* file (grunt-uglify)
- Concatanate all the uglified javascript files (grunt-concat)

The problem here is, sometimes, pulled commit may have some changes in *package.json*. Grunt caches *package.json* in the beginning of tasks so *package.json* is not affected by `git pull` which means grunt performs task according to old *package.json* file.

I'm looking for a solution which refreshes the cached *package.json* file so I it will run after git pull as expected.

**Edit**: You can find the whole process [here](https://gist.github.com/cihadturhan/5e8c7f03185509f912c7)

Here is the snippet I read files from package json:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        report: 'gzip',
        compress: true,
        banner: '<%= banner %>',
    },
    mangle: {
        toplevel: false
    },
    squeeze: {
        dead_code: false
    },
    codegen: {
        quote_keys: true
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            '<%= pkg.dirs.js.dist.min %>': '<%= pkg.dirs.js.dist.src %>'
        }
    }
}

concat: {
    js: {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= banner %>',
            stripBanners: true,
            separator: ';\n'
        },
        src: '<%= pkg.dirs.js.dev %>',
        dest: '<%= pkg.dirs.js.dist.src %>'
    },
    css: {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= banner %>',
            stripBanners: true,
            separator: ' \n'
        },
        src: '<%= pkg.dirs.css.dev %>',
        dest: '<%= pkg.dirs.css.dist.src %>'
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining what JS files to uglify from the `package.json` file?

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late response. I'm adding gruntfile and package file to description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something I don't think you can do simply from the basic config, I think you may need a custom task. The reason I say this is that you have to re-read the `package.json` file somehow, and there isn't a way to do that in the config (that I know of). So, instead, we can create a simple custom task that reads in the `package.json` file in between tasks 1 and 2. I wrote up a [couple blog posts](http://jordankasper.com/bending-grunt-to-your-will-with-custom-tasks-part-1/) on [custom tasks](http://jordankasper.com/bending-grunt-to-your-will-with-custom-tasks-part-2/) if you want to read up on it more.

Here's what I would do for the custom task:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('readpkg', 'Read in the package.json file', function() {

    grunt.config.set('pkg', grunt.file.readJSON('./package.json'));

});
```

Then we need to set up our multi-task for your setup:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('build', [ 'shell', 'readpkg', 'uglify:dist', 'concat:js' ]);
```

Obviously you may need to tweak those tasks. You can leave the initial reading of the `package.json` file in your Gruntfile.js config, it should just be overwritten by the `readpkg` task.